# Why do we need two different quantities (momentum and energy) to describe motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics, momentum

Different quantities mean momentum and energy.

Comment: momentum tells us the force and (potential) energy can tell us the position of an object in a conservative force field

Comment: You need [more than that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space).

Comment: As to why: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36GT2zI8lVA

Answer (score 2):

Neither momentum nor energy describe only the motion of an object. Both include mass. Motion itself is described by velocity.

Both energy and momentum are separately important because they are separately conserved. By Noether’s theorem they come from important symmetries in the laws of physics. Energy comes from the fact that the laws of physics are the same today and yesterday. Momentum comes from the fact that the laws of physics are the same here and there.